# Bind do CosmosDB no Azure Functions Local

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure, cosmos-db

Como fazer Bind do Azure CosmoDB pelo Visual Studio no Azure Functions?

Notem o código abaixo, o parâmetro inputDocument seria o Bind do CosmosDB. Quando criamos a Funcão direto no portal do Azure, o mesmo já faz isso automaticamente pois já cria as conexões no arquivo `local.settings.json`.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace CDPCompare
    {
        public static class CallWS
        {
            [FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
            public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, IEnumerable<dynamic> inputDocument)
            {
                foreach(var item in inputDocument)
                {
                    log.Info(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mostre o que vc já fez, e qual erro está ocorrendo, para podermos ajudar.

Comment: De uma lida neste post para entender como funciona a auto resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis valeu pela dica? Não estou conseguindo criar uma resposta para minha própria pergunta... Será porque ela está pendente?

Comment: Sim, quando uma pergunta está marcada como [pendente], [duplicada], [fechada] é impossível que você faça alterações nela @miltoncamara.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis Entendi... Vou aguardar ela ser reaberta então, falta mais um ponto! Muito obrigado :)

Comment: Foi votado para que fosse reaberta @miltoncamara e agora você pode reescrever o *post* corretamente. Faça suas edições e deixe seu *post* dentro do padrão do site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer o Bind em uma Function é necessário adicionar a seguinte configuração:

1 - Instalar o pacote Nuget `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB`

2 - Incluir o atributo `[DocumentDB("%DatabaseName%", "MyCollection")]` seguido do parâmetro `IEnumerable<dynamic> inputDocuments`

3 - Adicionar a string de conexão do CosmosDB no arquivo `local.settings.json` `"AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString":"STRING DE CONEXÃO COSMOS DB"`